# How can I add custom vote buttons to a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So here is an idea

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_one :vote
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

1. How can i limit the number of questions a user can ask?
2. Is there a better way of this?

Comment: Your Vote class, it should have `belongs_to :answer` and not to `:question` (or perhaps your `has_one` is on the wrong class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the first question:

Inside of the QuestionsController create method, you should just put some code that says something like:

```
if user.questions.length > 3
  #tell them they can't ask more questions
else
  #create the question
end
```

to the second:

Also, I don't think it makes sense to have Vote be it's own resource. I would just define 'vote' or 'votes' as a field on Answer. When an answer gets voted for, you just increment Answer.votes. Depends on your use case though

Comment: I'd prefer to have votes as its own resource that has a user_id associated with it, so that users can see what they have voted for, and perhaps even change their vote.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond, if you want to customize more in depth your validation, you can delegate the validation as so, assuming the `user_id` is the `user` column nested in the `question` model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with LengthValidator, :field => :user_id
....
end

class LengthValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if options[:fields].any?
     #put the above conditional of @Accipheran
  end
end
```